# Java Database Entity Inheritance

Tags: java, database, inheritance, polymorphism

In my database, I have 2 table is **Categories** and **Products**. 
The Products table has a **reference key** references to CategoryId in the Categories table.
And in my Java Project, I have 2 entities: Category and Product. 
So I wonder does the Product class have to **extends** Category class?

Comment: _does the Product class have to extends Category class?_ `Category` is a "property" of `product`

Comment: oh, thank you so much! I have finally understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case you need to add Category like a attribut in your Product Class.
You can add a list of Product in your Category class for biderctionnal relation.